# How to fix TemplateDoesNotExist Error on Windows10?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been following the tutorial for [Writing your first Django app][1]

In part 3, I was trying to use a template. I am working with Python 3.1, Django 3.2 on a Windows10.

Below is the error that I get:

```
  Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

  Using engine django:

   - django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 

      C:\Users\KKK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\index.html (Source does not exist)

   - django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 

      C:\Users\KKK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

Below is my file structure:

```
mysite
+-- mysite
|   +--settings.py
|   +--other files
+-- polls
|   +--templates
|   |   +--polls
|   |   |  +--index.html
|   +--views.py
|   +--other files
+-- db.sqlite3
+-- manage.py`
```

I added a reference to polls configuration class in the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to indicate to django where to find your templates, put this (somewhere around line 60) in settings.py

```
# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
]
```